# How to read connection strings from a SSIS package not from the config file

Tags: ssis

I Have a requirement like, i have to read the connection string values of an SSIS package without opening it via Visual studio.

Recently we had a problem like, the connection string hardcoded in the SSIS packages are not reflected in the config file. So we are planning to have a utility to get the connection string from the packages and compare it with the config files.

But i couldn't find a way to get the connection strings from the SSIS packages directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "config file"? Is this a Package Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This approach requires that you have the Integration Services components installed on your machine. Instantiate the Application and Package objects, enumerate all the values in the package's Connections collection. From there, inspect the ConnectionString object.

This approach does not factor in Expressions or Configurations.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts;

public static void FindConnections()
{
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        Package package = null;
        Application app = null;

        fileName = @"C:\sandbox\SSISHackAndSlash2008\SSISHackAndSlash2008\MyPackage.dtsx";
        package = new Package();
        app = new Application();
        app.LoadPackage(fileName, null);
        Connections packageConnections = package.Connections;
        // code approximate
        foreach(Connection conn in packageConnections)
        {
            Console.Writeline(conn.ConnectionString);
        }

}
```